# When the web page will be visible to the end user

Tags: javascript, dom-events

There are two events related to web page load - `ondomcontentloaded` and `onload`.

At which point will the user will be able to see the web page?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That really depends on the browser. Chrome and Firefox progressively render the webpage as it loads, even if HTML hasn't been completely sent. This will be happening before either of those events are triggered.

`onload` will always fire after `DOMContentLoaded`, so if you want the *earliest* event, use `DOMContentLoaded`.

Comment: ok, thanks . Can I say for most browserｓ, after the event DOMContentLoaded is triggered, user will be able to see the page framework?